# NSMutableArray in Swift: Different behavior on different ios version

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
protocol TestProtocol {

}

struct TestStruct: TestProtocol {

}

let arr = NSMutableArray()
let testStruct = TestStruct()
arr.add(testStruct)
print("\(arr[0] is TestProtocol)")
```

If I run this code in app on the simulator with IOS version >= 14.0 result is true, but on IOS 13 result is false.

Can someone tell me why there is difference of behavior?

Comment: Is the basis of your question curiosity, or trying to work around a problem this behavior presents? The simple answer to "why does this behavior change between iOS versions?" is that certain behaviors which are incidental to the implementation can change if the implementation changes a little; e.g., in iOS 13, `arr[0]` may return a different value than the same code in iOS 14, so the check behaves differently. Are you curious about the specifics of this, or do you need to write code that makes this work in iOS 13 too?

Comment: Yes, I need to fix this solution, preferably while keeping the usage objC collection. But you are also right, I'm curious why I get such a different result

Comment: If you write `print(type(of: arr[0]))` and run it on both versions of iOS, what do you see? And is there a reason you're using `NSMutableArray`? `NSMutableArray` comes from Objective-C, which cannot deal with Swift `struct` types directly. When you pass a `struct` to Objective-C (like inserting into `NSMutableArray`), it gets wrapped up inside of an object value to hold it (called `_SwiftValue`). My guess is that `arr[0]` on iOS 13 is giving you that `_SwiftValue` object back instead of unwrapping into your original `TestStruct` value, and `_SwiftValue` doesn't conform to the protocol.